# How do I access an instance variable of an outer class from within an inner class?

Tags: javascript, class

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Cookie{
    ChocolateChip = class{
        constructor(){
            
        }
        sayMyOuterClassName(){
            console.log(???);
        }
    }
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.someInstance = new this.ChocolateChip();
        this.someInstance.sayMyOuterClassName();
    }
}

let aCookie = new Cookie("Bob");
```

What do I replace `???` with in order to make it print out `"Bob"`? I saw someone suggest `Cookie.this.name`, but I'm afraid to try that without knowing all the implications of it, since I need to rely on the code I'm writing right now, and if it breaks in the future I don't want it to be because I used this line of code that I don't fully understand and end up wasting loads of time.

Aside from this question, I also want to ask... I was previously declaring my classes as static and using them like `new OuterClassName.InnerClassName()`, but I switched because I assumed that would prevent me from accessing instance variables from my outer class inside the inner classes... Is that correct? Does declaring an inner class as static prevent it from accessing its outer class' variables?

Comment: "I saw someone suggest `Cookie.this.name`" This doesn't work in all implementations I've tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to the parent:

```js
class Cookie{
    ChocolateChip = class {
        constructor(parent){
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        sayMyOuterClassName(){
            console.log(this.parent.name);
        }
    }
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.someInstance = new this.ChocolateChip(this);
        this.someInstance.sayMyOuterClassName();
    }
}

let aCookie = new Cookie("Bob");
```

Comment: I was afraid of exactly this... I really didn't want this to be the best solution.

Comment: @OOPSStudio Why? That's a very common pattern in many programming languages.

Comment: You're probably correct. To me it just feels very cluttering to my code, and it means that I need to reconfigure some arguments to position this required field among other optional fields, and I just know that it will cost me time in the future, knowing my structure. But I'll just adapt I guess. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> What do I replace `???` with in order to make it print out `"Bob"`?

Nothing, you can't do that in JavaScript without making further changes to your code. There is no intrinsic connection between `Cookie` and `ChocolateChip` other than that an instance property on a `Cookie` instance refers to an instance of `ChocolateChip`. The `Cookie.this.name` syntax you saw was Java, not JavaScript. Java and JavaScript are **very** different in this regard.

You may be misunderstanding the syntax you're using to create `ChocolateChip`. It **isn't** declaring an "inner class" (JavaScript doesn't have those). It's just creating an instance property and assigning a `class` expression to it via the [public class properties proposed syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which still is just a proposal (though very far along). Your code is functionally identical to this:

```
class Cookie{
    constructor(name){
        this.ChocolateChip = class{
            constructor(){
                
            }
            sayMyOuterClassName(){
                // console.log(???);
            }
        };
        this.name = name;
        this.someInstance = new this.ChocolateChip();
        this.someInstance.sayMyOuterClassName();
    }
}

let aCookie = new Cookie("Bob");
```

It creates a new `ChocolateChip` class for each instance of `Cookie`, and then creates an instance of that new class. But there's no link back from `ChocolateChip` to `Cookie` implemented by the language itself.

Comment: I know that Java and JavaScript are very different. However, the question whose answer contained that was tagged JavaScript... But maybe it was a mistake on the answerer's part.

Comment: @OOPSStudio - I suspect so, yes.

Comment: Actually, I didn't "change" anything, I merely fixed a typo. Your answer didn't "address a topic", it merely nitpicked a typo... So I wouldn't really consider me correcting a typo being "fundamentally changing my question", but alright. Also, I didn't downvote your answer, however I also won't upvote it since it isn't the answer I'm looking for and also isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @OOPSStudio - No, it didn't nitpick a typo. It called out what presented as a fundamental misunderstanding. It matched the belief that JavaScript had inner classes like Java that was apparent elsewhere, so I tackled that misunderstanding from multiple perspectives. I'm sorry you don't find it helpful to explain the relationship between the two classes.